# Getting size of an image(in kb or mb) selected from gallery programatically

Tags: android, file, uri, android-gallery, filesize

I am selecting an image from gallery.I want to determine the size of the image programatically in kb or mb.
This is what I have written:

```
public String calculateFileSize(Uri filepath)
{
    //String filepathstr=filepath.toString();
    File file = new File(filepath.getPath());

    // Get length of file in bytes
    long fileSizeInBytes = file.length();
    // Convert the bytes to Kilobytes (1 KB = 1024 Bytes)
    long fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
    // Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
    long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;

    String calString=Long.toString(fileSizeInMB);
    return calString;
}
```

The uri of the image when selected from gallery is coming perfectly.But the value of `fileSizeInBytes` is zero.I am calling this method on `onActivityResult` ,after selecting the image from gallery.I saw a few same questions asked here before.But none worked for me.Any solution?

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
public String calculateFileSize(Uri filepath)
{
  //String filepathstr=filepath.toString();
  File file = new File(filepath.getPath());

  long fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
  // Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
  long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;

  String calString=Long.toString(fileSizeInMB);
```

to

```
public String calculateFileSize(String filepath)
{
  //String filepathstr=filepath.toString();
  File file = new File(filepath);

  float fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
  // Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
  float fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;

  String calString=Float.toString(fileSizeInMB);
```

When you use `long` it will truncate all the digits after `.` So if your size is of less than 1MB you will get 0.

So instead use `float` in place of `long`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Not working.value of fileSizeInBytes returning 0.0....The uri is /external/images/media/1243

Comment: That is a path not an `Uri`. Check [fromFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile(java.io.File)) to see what a `Uri` looks like

Comment: then how can i get the size from imagepath??is it possible??

Comment: Check the edited answer. You need to change your argument and the way you create a `File`

Answer (score 4):

Just try this one and it will work for you

```
private void getImageSize(Uri choosen) throws IOException {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), choosen);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
        long lengthbmp = imageInByte.length;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Long.toString(lengthbmp),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

And on result

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                    if(selectedImage !=null){

                        img.setImageURI(selectedImage);

                        try {
                            getImageSize(choosenPhoto);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        //txt1.setText("Initial size: " +getImageSize(choosenPhoto)+ " Kb");
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a method for calculating image size chosen from the gallery. you can pass the Uri which you get from intent in onActivityResult :

```
public static double getImageSizeFromUriInMegaByte(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    double dataSize = 0;
    if (scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
        try {
            InputStream fileInputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                dataSize = fileInputStream.available();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE)) {
        String path = uri.getPath();
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = new File(path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (file != null) {
            dataSize = file.length();
        }
    }
    return dataSize / (1024 * 1024);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `uri.getLastPathSegment()` instead of `uri.getPath()`

```
public static float getImageSize(Uri uri) {

    File file = new File(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    return file.length(); // returns size in bytes
}
```

> IMPORTANT

The above code will only work for images that you pick from gallery; and doesn't work for those from file manager as it won't recognize the scheme of the URI

The below method will work in either case

```
public static float getImageSize(Context context, Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        float imageSize = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return imageSize; // returns size in bytes
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To change from bytes into Kbytes >>> /1024f

To change from bytes into Mbytes >>> /(1024f * 1024f)

Comment: Above solution is also mentioned in their official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info as well. So feel free to use it. Happy coding :)

Comment: @Smeet thanks for your added value appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean validImageSize() {
        try {
            if (bitmapPhoto!=null){
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();


                // Get length of file in bytes
                float imageSizeInBytes = imageInByte.length;
                // Convert the bytes to Kilobytes (1 KB = 1024 Bytes)
                float imageSizeInKB = imageSizeInBytes / 1024;
                // Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
                float imageSizeInMB = imageSizeInKB / 1024;
                return imageSizeInMB <= 1;
            }else {
                return true;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return true;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will return to you file from uri in new android and older

```
fun getFileFromUri(uri: Uri): File? {
if (uri.path == null) {
    return null
}
var realPath = String()
val databaseUri: Uri
val selection: String?
val selectionArgs: Array<String>?
if (uri.path!!.contains("/document/image:")) {
    databaseUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    selection = "_id=?"
    selectionArgs = arrayOf(DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri).split(":")[1])
} else {
    databaseUri = uri
    selection = null
    selectionArgs = null
}
try {
    val column = "_data"
    val projection = arrayOf(column)
    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
        databaseUri,
        projection,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        null
    )
    cursor?.let {
        if (it.moveToFirst()) {
            val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
            realPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.i("GetFileUri Exception:", e.message ?: "")
}
val path = if (realPath.isNotEmpty()) realPath else {
    when {
        uri.path!!.contains("/document/raw:") -> uri.path!!.replace(
            "/document/raw:",
            ""
        )
        uri.path!!.contains("/document/primary:") -> uri.path!!.replace(
            "/document/primary:",
            "/storage/emulated/0/"
        )
        else -> return null
    }
}
return File(path)}
```

and after you can use this for get file size

```
val file = getFileFromUri(your_uri)
val file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()/1024))
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Android there are many limitations for accessing direct file. We can use **ContentProviders** to get the size from Uri. Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

```
 fun getFileSize(uri: Uri): Long {
    val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver!!.query(
        yourFileUri, null, null, null, null
    )

    cursor?.use {
        val sizeColumn =
            it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE)
        if (it.moveToNext()) {
            return it.getLong(sizeColumn)
        }
    }
    return 0L
 }
```

you can also use below function to format the size

> android.text.format.Formatter.formatFileSize(context: Context?, sizeBytes: Long): String!